# Trying to figure out how to clip a vector with another vector (a rectangle box) using postgis

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, qgis

Technologies: PostGIS, QGIS

I have a vector box named "study_area", and another vector data "floodplain". Now I need to clip the floodplain vector data to produce a floodplain layer that is within in the study area. I am required to use postgis, writing queries for this specific job.

However, I checked the doc, it seems like the st_clip function only works for rasters.

Here is my attempt:

```
select r.geom as clipped
from study_area as s, usrname."Regulatory_Floodplain" as r
where st_within(r.geom, s.geom) or st_intersects(s.geom, r.geom)
```

The problem is that it is not entirely in the box:

[image]

Any alternatives? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [`ST_Intersection`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) function, something like

```
select st_intersection(r.geom, s.geom) as clipped
from study_area as s, usrname."Regulatory_Floodplain" as r
where st_intersects(s.geom, r.geom)
```

Comment: Aha it worked! Thank you! I thought that since my study_area layer is an empty box with only the boundary, using intersection will only give whatever is touching the boundary, but I am wrong. Thanks for your reply <3

Comment: please mark it as answer! it helps other users searching for similar questions to discover answers quicker.